# asp adds style=width:0px to gridview occationally

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble with the layout of some of my `asp:GridViews` because in almost half the cases of the GridViews I use, a `style=width:0px` is added in `element.style` and I have no idea where it comes from.

Does anyone have any idea why this only happens sometimes and how I can avoid it?

I can literally have the same grid on two different pages and one will get it, but the other won't and it's very frustrating.

[Image of weird width styling](https://imageshack.com/i/ezb840dbp)

Comment: I guess that depends on the browser...

Comment: Nope, it happens in all (at least FireFox, Chrome and Internet Explorer) Pretty sure it comes from when asp renders it, but then why does it only happen sometimes

Comment: On which exact html tag is that?

Comment: th and td in the rendered table. See edited post for image

Comment: Turns out some idiot has made a general class in the solution I'm working on for BoundFields in code behind that sets the width of HeaderStyle, ItemStyle and ControlStyle.